# How do i implement elasticsearch scripts in nodejs using elasticsearch npm

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I wanted to maintain a field in my ES doc that maintains the count of every time I make a request to that doc such as an update request. I am unable to make a syntax of a node query. Please help me with this.

My query on console is:

```
POST /test_index_1/_doc/{id}/_update
{
 "script" : "ctx._source.visits+=1",
 "upsert": {
  "visits": 1
 }
}
```

I want to make this Query in nodejs.

Comment: Is it just for update request?

Comment: right now, i need it for update only.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic manages document version by default. So instead of having own field and using script to update is for any update would be redundant and more error prone as if you miss to update the field the actual count would be lost. All this is managed by elastic search and I would suggest to leverage that.

So whenever there is an update in document elastic search increases the value of document version by one. To get the current version for each hit all you need to do is to add `"version": true` along with the search query as below:

```
{
  "version": true,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I got what you said but well i was doing it to implement a use case,  please help me solve this issue. link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57769058/11432290