# Is their any way using which i can restrict the number of children doc in my parent-child mapping in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES v7.3 and I am using parent-child mapping, I wanted to know is thier any way that i can restrict the number of child doc's for a parent document. suppose i have a parent 'p1' then i want that this parent must not have more than 100 child doc's associated with it and if some more doc's are indexed then the old child docs get deleted and new ones are indexed but the limit should be of 100 child docs.

```
PUT test/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "data": {
              "type": "join",
              "relations": {
                  "parent": ["child1", "child2", "child3"]
              }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your mappings of the parent-child relationship.

Comment: parent : ['child1',  'child2',  'child3'] this is the join datatype mapping b/w parent and child moreover in my doc's i have dynamic mapping.

Comment: Could you please be more specific and dump out the exact mappings from the mappings api.

Comment: their are more than 50 fields of type 'text' and type 'keyword' in the mappings.

Comment: So then please share the relevant section where the parent-child relationship with data type join is described.

Comment: added join mapping in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware that you could set such specific information about the maximum size and automatic delete via the mappings.

What you could do however is to implement a logstash filter that checks the size of the current number of child-documents and execute some REST-calls to the cluster if the number is already equal to 100.

I've never faced such an use case but I want to give you some possibilities for that workaround:

**1.) execute a parent_id-query via logstash's elasticsearch filter plugin**

As stated in the [parent_id documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-parent-id-query.html), this query "Returns child documents joined to a specific parent document".

So with the id of the parent document you should be able to get all child documents in your filter implementation. Refer to the [elasticsearch filter plugin documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) on how to use it. With that, you can surely determine the number of child-documents via a ruby code plugin.

**2.) check if the number of the current child documents is equal to 100**

**3.) if 2.) evaluates to true, call the delete_by_query REST API**

To index new child-documents without stepping over that maximum threshold of 100 child documents you have to delete previous indexed child documents. You could therefore use logstash's [http filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-http.html) to call the [delete_by_query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) with the exact query that will delete previous indexed documents.

**4.) index the new document via the elasticsearch output plugin**

Refer to the [Elasticsearch output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) on how to index events from logstash.

So as I stated at the beginning I am not fully aware whether this approach will lead to the desired result or not. But I would give it a try since the Logstash plugins I mentioned are able to do the particular steps in the workflow.

Comment: well this could be done if their's no other option left but i am looking for a more efficient and cheap approach, best if ES provides any such functionality.

Comment: Let me/us know if you have found a suitable option! :-)

Comment: hi, can u please help me with this issue..https://stackoverflow.com/q/57923166/11432290